# INSERT INTO Table From Two Temporary Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two temporary tables like below :

TempEmploye

```
Name    | Addres   | Title

SMITH   |CALIFORNIA| Example1
WAYNE   |BANDUNG   | Example2
ROSE    |PARIS     | Example3
```

TempTag

```
TAG   | ValueTag | Desc

AZ001 |Value1    | Desc1
AZ002 |Value2    | Desc2
AZ003 |Value3    | Desc3
```

Then I want `join` both temporary tables to one table with result like below:

TBResult

```
Name    | ValueTAG| Desc

SMITH   |AZ001    | Desc1
SMITH   |AZ002    | Desc2
SMITH   |AZ003    | Desc3
WAYNE   |AZ001    | Desc1
WAYNE   |AZ002    | Desc2
WAYNE   |AZ003    | Desc3
ROSE    |AZ001    | Desc1
ROSE    |AZ002    | Desc2
ROSE    |AZ003    | Desc3
```

I'm trying do it using this code, but it doesn't work:

```
INSERT  INTO tbResult(NAME, VALUETAG, DESC)
SELECT (select NAME from #TempEmploye) VALUETAG, DESC
FROM #TempTag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no common field to join two tables..u can use `Cross Join`

```
INSERT  INTO tbResult
    (NAME,
     VALUETAG,
     DESC)
    SELECT 
       e.Name,
       t.ValueTag
       t.Desc
    FROM TempEmployee e 
    CROSS JOIN TempTag t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT  INTO tbResult(NAME, VALUETAG, DESC)
SELECT E.NAME,T.VALUETAG, T.DESC
FROM #TempTag T
CROSS JOIN #TempEmploye E
```

NOTE: Be careful trying to use `DESC` as column name because is SQL reserved word. If you have problems with `DESC` try to add `[]` as below

```
INSERT  INTO tbResult(NAME, VALUETAG, [DESC])
SELECT E.NAME,T.VALUETAG, T.DESC
FROM #TempTag T
CROSS JOIN #TempEmploye E
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT  INTO tbResult
(NAME, VALUETAG, DESC)
SELECT te.NAME, tt.VALUETAG, tt.DESC
FROM #TempTag tt
Cross Join #TempEmployee te
```

Comment: I'd like to see a bit more explanation on why or how this works or what exactly it does.

Comment: Cross join produces a cartesian product.  Each row in set a is joined to each row in set b.  I've rarely used it in production myself, but this is the rare situation where that's what you actually want.  Let me dig up a link

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins. This is what I used to explain joins when my wife started learning sql

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT  INTO tbResult(NAME, VALUETAG, DESC)
SELECT e.NAME, t.VALUETAG, t.DESC FROM #TempEmploye e CROSS JOIN #TempTag t
```